# Check if String Contains Letters with If and Else Statements

Tags: javascript

I have a string named `uppercase` and if it contains letters, nothing happens. Although, if it doesn't then it evaluates `uppercase`. Here's my `if` and `else` statement:

```
  if(uppercase.substring(0,9) == "CALCULATE")
  {
    if(uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length.contains("[a-zA-Z]+")))
    {
    } else{
      var ans = eval(uppercase.substring(9,uppercase.length));
      sendSpecialChat = [true, ans];
      }
  }
```

Although, it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you provide value of `uppercase` variable inline in the post and also clarify what you've found stepping through this code in debugger?

Comment: You probably meant to close the brackets after `uppercase.length` here: `if(uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length.contains("[a-zA-Z]+")))`. Also, contains() has been superceded by includes() and doesn't take a regex. Use match() instead

Comment: `uppercase.length.contains`? *uppercase.length* will return a number, they don't have a *contains* property. Perhaps you meant `...(10,uppercase.length).contains(...)`?

Comment: @samgak—I don't think *contains* was ever part of ECMAScript, I can't find it in any spec. from ed 3 onward. There is a *contains* in the Node interface, but that's in regard to DOM elements, not a built–in String method.

Comment: @RobG it was supported by Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains

Comment: @samgak—thanks. Another example of why extending built–ins is not a good idea… ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your issue is here:

> ```
> uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length.contains("[a-zA-Z]+")
> ```

If you are testing if the part of *uppercase* contains any letters beyond the 10th character (allowing for zero index), then you can use substring with a suitable regular expression, e.g.:

```
/[a-z]/i.test(uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length))
```

```js
var uppercase = "0123456789Hey"

console.log('"' + uppercase + '" : ' + 
            /[a-z]/i.test(uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length)));

var uppercase = "0123456789*&^"

console.log('"' + uppercase + '" : ' + 
            /[a-z]/i.test(uppercase.substring(10,uppercase.length)));
```

Or just a regular expression:

```js
var uppercase = "0123456789Hey";

console.log('"' + uppercase + '" : ' + /^.{10}[a-z]/i.test(uppercase));

var uppercase = "0123456789*&^";

console.log('"' + uppercase + '" : ' + /^.{10}[a-z]/i.test(uppercase));
```